# How to start on BPM business process modeling

Tags: business-process-management

I guess the question is too broad, but anyway.

What is the best option to move to BPM as a programmer/developer? Is there any open source project that I can go for and get some experience.

Any specific tool, ideas, link or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Your question is a little too vague, I think. It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: I have some java skills and would like to move to some BPM technology. No changes to do this on my day job. So the questions is what tools can start to learn? Therefore in the long-term I can get a job on this area

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense. Answer will be up shortly, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Business Process Modelling Notation (aka BPM) isn't really a 'technology'. It's a way of documenting the way in which a business works - it's various processes. It's often a part of systems/business analysis and perhaps the simplest way of explaining it is that it's a 'flowchart' of everything a business does.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modelling) gives a decent overview with links to a few modelling tools available.

Hope that's of help to you.

Comment: thank for the answer, but is there any open source initiative that I can get involved? The point is to have hands-on because only theory is not get "you" there.

Comment: I would definitely suggest that you learn the theory first - or at least get some idea of it. Then take a look at getting involved with a project in a systems analysis role. I don't know of any OSS projects where you could use BPMN - it tends to be used more in businesses where bespoke systems are needed. It is, after all, an analysis tool.

Answer (score 5):

BPM indeed started as a way of managing and documenting business processes. But Alex is probably looking for a BPMS (S. for "system") that is, software and tools that allow you to not only document but also implement those processes in software.

Among the open source BPM systems, two of the most known ones are:

- jBPM: http://jboss.org/jbpm
- Activiti (started by the founders of jBPM): http://www.activiti.org/

Answer (score 2):

Another open sourced alternative that you should check out is Joget Workflow (www.joget.org). They're fairly young but definitely very promising.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to study some important concepts about BPM and BPMN. If you need a BPMS to provide a good way to learn BPM, I suggest you to take look on [Bizagi](http://www.bizagi.com). It is a very powerfull an well documented BPMS tool. It's a piece of cake to automate process using it.
But, if you really need to Open Source tool, there are just two good project that you could try: [Bonitasoft](http://www.bonitasoft.com/) and [Intalio](http://www.intalio.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add Bonita BPM for you to evaluate:

[BonitaBPM Download](http://www.bonitasoft.com/products/BPM_download_current)

It's a good documented open source BPMS project:

[Bonita BPM Documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com)

According to Gartner

> ...the only open-source product that meets Gartner's definition of a BPMS

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [blog](http://devbackyard.blogspot.pt/) which provides an overview of the main BPMS existing in the market.